# How to create an unique index in an array of subdocuments in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a document in mongodb to save stock quotes. The top level document has two keys - ticker and quotes. Ticker is a string and quotes is a list of quotes with dates.

I am easily able to create an  unique index on ticker so no duplicate tickers are saved:

`db.aggregates_1_day.createIndex( { "ticker": 1 }, { unique: true } )`

But I am not sure how to do that for the date field - that is in an array. As you can notice in the document, there are duplicate dates in that field.

```
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6384349542996315343d33ed"),
    ticker: 'ABR',
    quotes: [
      {
        volume: 1103639,
        open: 17.15,
        close: 17.2,
        high: 17.44,
        low: 17.117,
        transactions: 10225,
        date: '2022-02-07'
      },
      {
        volume: 1103639,
        open: 17.15,
        close: 17.2,
        high: 17.44,
        low: 17.117,
        transactions: 10225,
        date: '2022-02-07'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Thanks much for the help.

Comment: [_"Unique Multikey Index: For unique indexes, the unique constraint applies across separate documents in the collection rather than within a single document."_](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-multikey/#unique-multikey-index).  Your app/updates will need to insure there are no duplicates within a single document's array - perhaps by using `"$addToSet"` rather than `"$push"` when updating a document.

Comment: This is helpful as now I understand my code was not working.